# Difference between router-link and RouterLink in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When using Vue Router, I found that I could use `<router-link>` as well as `RouterLink` to achieve the same result, i.e. navigate between different routes.

Similarly, there's `<router-view>` as well as `RouterView` component.

Following two code examples give me the same result:

With `<router-link>` and `<router-view>`:

```
<template>
  <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  <hr />
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

With `<RouterLink>` and `<RouterView>`:

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from "vue-router";
</script>

<template>
  <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
  <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
  <hr />
  <RouterView />
</template>
```

**Question**

What is the difference between `<router-link>` and `RouterLink` (and between `<router-view>` and `RouterView`?)

I couldn't find anything on Vue Router docs. Searching for `RouterView` or `RouterLink` doesn't show any results related to them. Docs only mention `<router-link>` and `<router-view>`.

**P.S.** Scaffolding a new Vue project with `npm init vue@latest` command uses `RouterLink` and `RouterView` components instead of `router-link` and `router-view`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same components, just with different cases, in vue it's recommended to use the `PascalCase` syntax as mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component) :

> In SFCs, it's recommended to use PascalCase tag names for child components to differentiate from native HTML elements. Although native HTML tag names are case-insensitive, Vue SFC is a compiled format so we are able to use case-sensitive tag names in it. We are also able to use /> to close a tag.

Comment: If `PascalCase` is the recommended naming convention, is there a specific reason why vue-router uses `kebab-case` in its examples?

Comment: The most common syntax is kebab case for Vue apps despite the recommendation. Not difference functionally. @Yousaf

Comment: @Yousaf I think they written in kebab-case since those components are different than native elements

Answer (score 3):

They are the same thing. Any component can be used either by writing its name as PascalCase or kebab-case.

Answer (score 3):

One is the component name and one is the vue class. I don't think there is a difference. If you would create your own component e.g. MyComponent.vue, you can also use  <MyComponent> or <my-component>